# Привести данные с MySQL для графиков Google Charts

Tags: php, mysql, chart.js, google-chart

Для дальнейшего подключения Google Charts необходимо, чтобы выходные данные имели вид

```
data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 1],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 2],
          ['Zucchini', 2],
          ['Pepperoni', 1]
        ]);
```

Есть такой скрипт, который подсчитывает кол-во постов по месяцам

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "login", "pas","baza"); 

$Requete = "SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%u'),
    COUNT(1)
FROM
    `dle_post`
WHERE
    date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%u')";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $Requete) or die("1" . mysqli_error($db));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo json_encode($row[0]);
echo json_encode($row[1]);  


    // очищаем результат
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: Требования понятны, с чем у вас проблемы для их достижения?

Answer (score 0):

Решение было прямо под рукой. Теперь одним запросом считает по неделям количество постов.

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "логин", "пароль","база"); 


$Requete = "SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%u'),
    COUNT(1)
FROM
    `dle_post`
WHERE
    date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%u')";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $Requete) or die("1" . mysqli_error($db));


while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$pole1=$row[0];
$pole2=$row[1];


echo "<br>Постов в $pole1 неделю >$pole2";
}



    // очищаем результат
    mysqli_free_result($result);
```